Should the shares be visible in the Windows and Ubuntu network folders?
My laptop host is Windows 11 Home. The VirtualBox guest VM is Ubuntu 22.04.

Ubuntu IP: 192.168.56.102
Windows IP: 192.168.56.11

Both the host and guest are in the same WORKGROUP.
I can access the shares directly from the file managers from the host OS and guest OS:

From Windows 11: \\192.168.56.102\share
From Ubuntu: smb://192.168.56.11/share

Everything appears to work as designed. Here is the burning question that has plagued Windows and Samba networking.
Why don't I see the COMPUTER names in the network folders of the file managers? Since SMB1 is deprecated, should I see them?
When I run smbclient I get the following.
Query the Ubuntu guest address:
# smbclient -L \\192.168.56.102 -U root
Password for [WORKGROUP\root]:

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
    share           Disk      Samba on Ubuntu 22.04
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service
    HP Printer      HP Deskjet 4100
SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available

Query the Windows host address:
# smbclient -L \\192.168.56.11 -U root
Password for [WORKGROUP\root]:
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE


I think you answered your own question.
"Computer name" in this context refers to the NetBIOS name of the machines. NetBIOS is a SMBv1 thing and without it there is no NetBIOS. Neither Windows or Samba enable SMBv1 by default.
Windows uses another method to "discover" hosts on the network and that is WS-Discovery.
In Ubuntu 22.04 you can enable WS-Discovery server side with the wsdd package:
sudo apt install wsdd

This would enable Win10/11 discovery of your Linux samba server in Explorer.
In Ubuntu 22.04 it only works one way. Windows can discover Linux but not the other way around.
In Ubuntu 24.04 there is a slightly different implementation and is enabled with the wsdd-server package. Ironically this also enables ws-discovery on the client side of Linux so it can discover Win10/11 hosts

Yes, I kind of did, but I needed confirmation. Add thanks for the additional information. I did not know about he wsdd implementation in Samba. Should I disable the nmbd service since wsdd is the best way to see the computer name in the browse list?

You can. I usually just disable it in smb.conf itself. There's an option you can add to the [global] section that will disable it: disable netbios = yes

I also discovered disabling SMBv1 server feature in Windows 11 helped. Ubuntu and Windows were competing on being the MSBROWSE master.
